# Texture[] not working properly with Image AlphaChannel

Tags: graphics, textures, opacity

I recently encountered a problem when combining multiple texture layers in an graphics object when the texture comes from an image with alpha channel. Apparently the alpha channel of the image passed to `Texture[]` as an argument is not represented as it should be in the obtained Graphics object. Instead of delivering true transparent texels I just get non transparent white ones. The same issue applies to usage of `Texture[]` with `Graphics3D`.

Here is a simple test case:

I first create two images, the second one containing an alpha channel:

```
layer1 = Image[RandomReal[1, {12, 12, 3}]];
layer2 = SetAlphaChannel[Image[RandomReal[1, {12, 12, 3}]], 
   Image[Join[ConstantArray[0, {6, 12}], ConstantArray[1, {6, 12}]]]];
```

Then I lay layer2 on top of layer1 and create a Graphics object of each layer using a Texture on a polygon:

```
Graphics[{Texture[layer1], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
  Texture[layer2], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

Unfortunately I only get white pixels where layer2 should be transparent. 
[image]

If I just pass the ImageData of layer2 things work, but the rest of the image information is lost (notice the additional blurring):

```
Graphics[{Texture[layer1], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
  Texture[layer2//ImageData], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: why don't you use `ImageCompose[Image[layer1], Image[layer2]]`.

Comment: @Blackbird: Don't be fooled by the example above. This is just a simple example that everyone can use to reproduce the problem. I actually use the above procedure with Graphics3D and mapping of the texture on different planes. The same problem appears there.

Comment: You can check the Heike's answer here. You may find it useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458675/fastest-way-to-create-a-transparent-image-in-mathematica-8-or-above

Comment: @s.s.o: Unfortunately the link does not help with the problem at hand. Setting the alpha channel is not the problem here. The problem seems to be using an image object that contains an alpha channel with `Texture[]`.