# How to make Texture unblurred?

Tags: graphics, image-processing, textures

This post is related to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34567/texture-not-working-properly-with-image-alphachannel), But somewhat different. Since Wizard focus on alpha channel, and didn't got an answer. So I made this post.

My system is Windows 10, and Mathematica 11.2

If I run

```
plot = Image[RandomReal[1., {6, 6}]]
```

I got

[image]

Then I texture this image on a square like this

```
Graphics[{Texture[plot], EdgeForm[],
  Append[Polygon @@ RegionBoundary[Rectangle[]], 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

I got

[image]

You can see it is already blurred

What is worse, if we generate a color image

```
plot = Image[RandomReal[1., {6, 6, 3}]]
```

[image]

and texture it.

```
Graphics[{Texture[plot], EdgeForm[],
  Append[Polygon @@ RegionBoundary[Rectangle[]], 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

I got

[image]

Which is a total mess.

The difference between my result and Wizard's result is that, even I don't set alpha channel, I already screw up the color image texture.

So why `Texture` always blur image? I check the doc, it seems that this blurring feature is not mentioned. Is it possible to make `Texture` clear especially for color image generated by `Image`?

---

**update**

Thanks to J.M. and kglr. They both suggest that it is a problem of low-res of image. But I have a counter example, which suggest that there is some subtle effect. Take a look at this, using `ArrayPlot`

```
plot = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1., {6, 6}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Frame -> None]
```

[image]

then texture it with the same method,

```
Graphics[{Texture[plot], EdgeForm[],
  Append[Polygon @@ RegionBoundary[Rectangle[]], 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

you will got

[image]

You will notice there is still some blur, but much weaker. And the color is much much better than `Image` texture, but seems not as vivid as original plot.

If you test `ImageDimensions@plot`. Both `ArrayPlot` and `Image` generate 6x6 image. So at least, this example shows low-res may not be a real reason for poor texture of `Image`

Comment: try `plot = Image[RandomReal[1., {6, 6}], ImageSize -> 500]`?

Comment: This seems to be a problem when your images are low-res. At least for this simple case, try `plotNew = ImageResize[plot, Scaled[50], Resampling -> "Nearest"]; Graphics[{Texture[plotNew], EdgeForm[], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]`

Comment: Hi, @kglr. I tried `ImageSize`, doesn't work

Comment: matheorem, it works in version 9.  J.M's suggestion works in both version 9 and 11.

Comment: `Rasterize[plot ,RasterSize ->500, ImageResolution -> 300 ]` also works  in both v9 an v11.

Comment: Hi, @J.M.  Your solution works. But I don't understand why it is a problem of low-res. Because the image generated by bare `Image` is quite sharp when dragged to enlarge

Comment: @kglr Thanks, you are right

Comment: @J.M. That is a answer..

Comment: @yode, I'm not sure that procedure is generalizable, tho.

Comment: @matheorem, it looks that way on the frontend, sure, but you've seen what actually happens on `Texture[]`, since it has to interpolate.

Comment: Hi, @J.M. I add an update : ）

Comment: Point 7 under "More Details" of the docs for `Texture[]`: "`Texture[obj]` is equivalent to `Texture[Rasterize[obj]]` and will rasterize `obj` at the size and resolution it would normally be displayed in a notebook." With that, try `plot = Rasterize[ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1., {6, 6}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> None]]; ImageDimensions[plot]`.

Comment: The problem is one of [texture filtering](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures) (scroll down to the "Texture Filtering" section on that page). Most graphics APIs allow one to choose between nearest neighbour (which is what you want) and bilinear filtering (which is what Mathematica does), but it seems Mathematica doesn't give you that choice. So you'll have to work around it, either by creating a high-resolution texture, or by creating lots of little squares and colouring them individually.

Comment: @J.M. Wow, This is indeed subtle. The dimension of rasterized result is different for `ArrayPlot` and `Image`!

Comment: @Rahul Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @J.M. There is still one thing I don't understand. I found the `AbsoluteTiming` of  `Rasterize[Image@RandomReal[1., {300, 300, 3}]]` is much longer than `Graphics[{Texture[Image@RandomReal[1., {300, 300, 3}]], EdgeForm[], 
  Append[Polygon @@ RegionBoundary[Rectangle[]], 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]`. This doesn't make any sense if Texture[obj] is equivalent to Texture[Rasterize[obj]]

Comment: My understanding is that `Texture[expr]` will only use `Rasterize[]` if `expr` is not already an `Image[]` or an array of RGB triplets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rahul is correct in his comment. To map a texture to an object, you use `VertexTextureCoordinates` to specify where the texture is *glued* to the object. The problem is, that those few points are not enough because you need a color for every single position inside your polygon.

When you know the coordinates of your polygon that are mapped to the texture corners, you can map each point inside the polygon to point of the texture. These calculated points will almost never lie on a perfect pixel and you will not have exactly as many points as you have image pixels.

The question is, how do you calculate the color at pixel position (2.34, 4.003)? You interpolate the pixels of your texture. As Rahul pointed out, bilinear interpolation is used. When we know this, we can recreate the artifact ourselves. Just take your image and create a larger one with linear resampling:

```
plot = Image[RandomReal[1., {6, 6, 3}]];
ImageResize[plot, 128, Resampling -> "Linear"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since it seems we cannot set (I haven't looked carefully!) the interpolation aka "Texture Filtering" in Mathematica, one choice is to create a larger image by resampling linearly yourself and use a larger texture image:

```
plot = Image[RandomReal[1., {6, 6, 3}]];
tex = ImageResize[plot, 256, Resampling -> "Constant"];

Graphics[{Texture[tex], EdgeForm[], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is not perfect, but way better.

Comment: Thank you so much, halirutan. Very clear : )

Answer (score 1):

There is a Method option for Graphics(3D) to set the texture sampling to constant (nearest):

```
Graphics[{Texture[tex], EdgeForm[], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 Method -> {"TextureSampling" -> "Nearest"}]
```

It does well for up-scaling in the middle, but there are artifacts around the outer edge due to the repeating nature of textures. This edge-artifact is more noticeable if the texture is used in Graphics and less noticeable (to me) in Graphics3D.